# Sqlite database cannot read column

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite

I have a `DBManager` wich is fetching data from database (sqlite file). All other queries are fine, but this one seems to be somehow not working

```
-(NSArray *)readCountries{
NSLog(@"[DBManager] readCountries");
NSMutableArray *countriesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//open db from users filesystem
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char* sql = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM aed ORDER BY rowid";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //loop through results
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            //read data from record
            NSString *_country;
            char* tmpCountry = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSLog(@"tmpCountry = %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmpCountry]);
            if (tmpCountry != NULL) {
                _country = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmpCountry];
            }else{
                _country = @"n/a";
            }
            NSLog(@"country = %@", _country);
            [countriesArray addObject:_country];
        }
    }
    //finalize statement
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
//close database
sqlite3_close(database);
NSLog(@"[DBManager] countriesArray has %d objects", [countriesArray count]);
return (NSArray*)countriesArray;
```

}

All I get from logs, that my array has 5 objects, which is fine - but it souldn't be only "n/a"... any idea? Other queries are good, they mostly use `sqlite3_column_text` so I don't get it, why it's not working here - maybe a fresh eye will help.

Comment: What rmaddy said about logging -- as written your code will silently fail rather than letting you know what's wrong.  (And sqlite3_errmsg is often quite informative.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusing inconsistency with the `sqlite` C-api. When using the `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions, the column index is 0-based. But with the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions, the column index is 1-based.

Change this:

```
char* tmpCountry = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
```

to:

```
char* tmpCountry = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
```

BTW - you should add `else` statements to your `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_prepare` calls. If they fail you can log the error using the `sqlite3_errmsg` function.

Comment: Should be checking the return code from sqlite3_step as well, though it takes a bit more work since you must filter out SQLITE_DONE before assuming an error.

Comment: thanks man, though I did have 0 at some point it didn't work now it does - looks like xcode also needed some sleep time ;)